# can you have both asp.net mvc 1 and 2 installed side by side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

i need to have one project on asp.net mvc 1 but i want to upgrade for another project.  is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.  See [Scott Guthrie's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/11/asp-net-mvc-2-released.aspx) for more information.

> ASP.NET MVC 2 can be installed
>   side-by-side with ASP.NET MVC 1
>   (meaning you can have some apps built
>   with V1 and others built with V2 on
>   the same machine).  We have
>   [instructions on how to update](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet-mvc2-upgrade-notes/) your
>   existing ASP.NET MVC 1 apps to use
>   ASP.NET MVC 2 using VS 2008 [here](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet-mvc2-upgrade-notes/). 
>   Note that VS 2010 has an automated
>   upgrade wizard that can automatically
>   migrate your existing ASP.NET MVC 1
>   applications to ASP.NET MVC 2 for you.